# ++i vs i++ in javascript confusing function

Tags: javascript, arrays

What would be the difference between

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
nums[i] = i+1;
}
```

and

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
nums[i] = i+1;
}
```

In the `for` loop, `i = 0`, but in the first iteration, would nums[i] = nums [0] or nums [1] since we are using `++i`? How would the first iteration be different if `i++` were used instead?

Update: For this particular `for` loop it doesn't matter. However, I'm interested to see a `for` loop where `++i` vs `i++` matters.

Comment: There is no difference. The first iteration in both would be nums[0].

Answer (score 5):

They would be exactly the same; `++i` and `i++` have the same *effect* on `i`, but the *value* of each expression is different; in this context, since the value is ignored, the code behaves the same.

As an example where switching between the two *would* matter, here is some truly awful code:

```
for ( var i=0; i++ < 10; )
```

Comment: Can you provide a for loop in which i++ and ++i would matter?

Answer (score 2):

`++i` increments before the "return", `i++` increments after

```
var i = 0;
i++; //=> 0
i;   //=> 1

var j = 0;
++j; //=> 1
j;   //=> 1
```

For the purposes of your `for` loop, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two. The incremented value will be ignoreed as it will happen at the end of the loop.

**EDIT:**

It makes no difference in the for loop if you write

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

You will get the same results in both the cases. The reason why most of the people use i++ or better to say why i++ is more popular over ++i in a for loop is probably because people come from a habit of using i++ which was majorly used in C. Also to note that in C++ you can write your own version of ++ operator.

Answer (score 0):

In for loops, there is no difference. The difference between ++i and i++ is the value returned by the expression, but the expression is evaluated after each pass of the loop and you ignore the value.

Answer (score -1):

They are the same. The increment occurs at the end of the body of the loop.

i.e. you can view the loop as

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {

... Body of loop

i++ or ++i;

}
```